# Get [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017] when I deploy my project in heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

My project works fine locally.

And I push my project into GitHub and Heroku by using command:

```
git add .
git commit -m "msg"
git push 
git push Heroku
```

I got error when I tried to access `https://still-shelf-36108.herokuapp.com/`
I checked `Heroku logs`. The error is below:

```
READY  Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:12211                    15:03:24
2019-02-28T15:03:24.419308+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-02-28T15:03:24.729864+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:42) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

Anyone can help to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this is that your localhost and the Heroku's localhost are not the same. Therefore a database hosted on your localhost is not accessible from https://still-shelf-36108.herokuapp.com/.

To solve this, you can create a free MongoDB instance at https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas and then connect from both your localhost and from your Heroku app.